# formating string in python with a condition

Tags: python-2.7

I need to format my list to a string with some exceptions, like if I have  `["00", "01", "01x", "XX", "YY"]`, I would like to have  `"'00':'01':'01x':XX:YY".`. I can concatenate with ':' but I cannot add the '' around 00, 01, 01x. How can we do a conditional formatting?

`":".join('{}'.format(x) for x in list)`  is what I have at the moment to concatenate the list.

Comment: You can update your list with single quotes and then create your final string, check my answer below @user1958532

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the updated list with single quotes around the items you want to have single quotes around before you create the final string via join. We can search those items via [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re

li = ["00", "01", "01x", "XX", "YY"]

#Append single quotes around the items we want to, and search matching items via regex
li = ["'{}'".format(item) if item in re.findall('0*1*x*', item) else item for item in li ]
#["'00'", "'01'", "'01x'", 'XX', 'YY']

#Create the string
print(":".join('{}'.format(x) for x in li))
#'00':'01':'01x':XX:YY
```

Comment: I can't do that because it could be if any order its just an example. It could be with multiple 0/ 1 or x and in any combination.

Comment: Sure! Updated my answer to handle that @user1958532 I am using regex to match 0 or more occurences or 0,1 and X Also will 0 always come before 1 and x always come before 1, or can the order change? Also if my answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted :)